# Is there a way to change the site title url in wordpress through css?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Im using wordpress.com to host my blog. When you click on the site image, it takes you back to the blog home page and not the homepage the belongs to my site.

I know how to change this with an installed wordpress through the editor menu. 
However, I dont have any of these option on wordpress.com, however, I have full access to mutate stuff through css.

Is there a way to force CSS to make the changes for me.

```
<a href="http://blog.site.com/" title="site" rel="home">Site</a>
```

However, I want it to read

```
<a href="http://site.com/" title="site" rel="home">Site</a>
```

Just to recap, I dont have an option to change this through the editor. My only option of changing this is through CSS.

I was thinking to use something like [this](http://www.cssportal.com/css-properties/text-replace.htm) to replace the text inside the herf. But I cant even get it to work with the example text. 
Thanks a million.

Comment: They look exactly the same :o

Comment: `.come` is an interesting address but those two lines are identical. And CSS deals with _styling_ and not so much content.

Comment: You say you have full access to mutate stuff through CSS; do you have the ability to insert Javascript?

Comment: Can javascript be inside the CSS file?

Answer (score 2):

No - CSS is a read-only way to style page content, not change the content itself (which that tag is a part of).